# determining the intrinsic size of a UIStackView before display on the screen

Tags: ios, uistackview

I would like to determine the instrinstic size of a stack view before displaying it on the screen. The idea is to use it as part of a pull up menu from the bottom of the screen but when I query the object before it appears it has size (-1,-1). Is there anything I should do first before my call to instrinsic content size?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`UIStackView` has no intrinsic content size. You're getting -1 because that is the value of `UIView.noIntrinsicMetric`.

Instead, ask for its fitting size:

```
let size = stackView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
```

Comment: I think this works. Still need to sort out logic for the rest of the code but it gives the correct dimensions back.

Comment: for ios9 this stackView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize will crash intermittently.  I'm trying to see if there is a way around this.

Comment: I'm also seeing a -1 so that makes sense.  But how do you know UIStackView doesn't have an intrinsicContentSize?  UIStackview inherits from UIView so wouldn't it have this property?

Comment: It has a property named `intrinsicContentSize`. When I say “`UIStackView` has no intrinsic content size”, I mean that the value of the property, for a `UIStackView`, is `CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric)`.